# Using package listings with sciposter

Tags: listings, line-breaking, columns, sciposter

Could you please provide a working example in which a source code delimited by `listings` environment word wraps its lines, without breaking the column layout of `sciposter`?

Whenever I put a long line in the middle column, for instance, it is rendered until it ends (`\textwidth` is the limit), therefore breaking the column layout.

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

Setting the `breaklines` flag solved the word-wrapping problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981020/how-to-force-line-wrapping-in-listings-package

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  If you can't get it to compile at least post what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

To get automatic line breaking with `listings` you need to specify `breaklines=true`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consectetur nulla a ante ullamcorper sed mattis massa fringilla. Mauris et leo nisl. Sed tortor lorem, vestibulum ut fermentum a, sollicitudin in arcu. Vivamus leo purus, imperdiet quis scelerisque et, varius non enim. Nunc scelerisque velit et dui porttitor at vulputate lorem convallis. Nam vitae erat ac urna semper adipiscing. Proin quis justo nibh. Proin ultricies ultricies libero. Nunc sodales sapien vel purus ultricies sodales. Curabitur non semper magna. Nullam varius dapibus leo, ac imperdiet nulla tempus vitae. In et turpis ut turpis facilisis tristique. Phasellus interdum, justo a semper aliquam, ante diam consequat justo, a egestas nisi lorem sit amet erat. Nam justo nunc, vulputate ac luctus et, ullamcorper eu mi. Pellentesque ut dui nulla, ut sagittis dui. Donec eget ligula non dui tristique auctor at vel sapien. 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```