# Handling Truncated Listings

Tags: listings

I included some listing in my document using the listings package but some of the lines are rather long and are being truncated. How do I best handle this issue?

Comment: Use `breaklines=true` and `breakwhitespace=true`. See this for a good example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38579/full-width-code-listing-within-two-column-text of settings.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

As  Yiannis Lazarides commented, you need to add `breaklines=true`. Here is an example copied from my earlier answer to this question on [Using package listings with sciposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34543/using-package-listings-with-sciposter/34544#34544):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consectetur nulla a ante ullamcorper sed mattis massa fringilla. Mauris et leo nisl. Sed tortor lorem, vestibulum ut fermentum a, sollicitudin in arcu. Vivamus leo purus, imperdiet quis scelerisque et, varius non enim. Nunc scelerisque velit et dui porttitor at vulputate lorem convallis. Nam vitae erat ac urna semper adipiscing. Proin quis justo nibh. Proin ultricies ultricies libero. Nunc sodales sapien vel purus ultricies sodales. Curabitur non semper magna. Nullam varius dapibus leo, ac imperdiet nulla tempus vitae. In et turpis ut turpis facilisis tristique. Phasellus interdum, justo a semper aliquam, ante diam consequat justo, a egestas nisi lorem sit amet erat. Nam justo nunc, vulputate ac luctus et, ullamcorper eu mi. Pellentesque ut dui nulla, ut sagittis dui. Donec eget ligula non dui tristique auctor at vel sapien. 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```